# Compute the least upper bound of the set of all real numbers of the form $Re(iz^3 +1)$ such that $|z| \leq 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute the least upper bound of the set of all real numbers of the form $Re(iz^3 +1)$ such that $|z| \leq 1$.

Could someone please lead me in the right direction on how I begin to solve this? This is for my complex variables class, but it was a challenge problem.

Comment: you might notice that $ |z|\le 1$  if and only if  |$iz^3|\le 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find $\sup \operatorname{im}{f}$ where $f(z) = Re(iz^3 +1)$.

$z \stackrel{g}{\mapsto} z^3$ is a homeomorphism $\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$. So, $\operatorname{im}{g} = \mathbb D$.

$z \stackrel{h}{\mapsto}iz$ is also a homeomorphism so $\operatorname{im}{h \circ g} = \mathbb D$.

Finally, $z \stackrel{k}{\mapsto}z+1$ is a translation of $\mathbb D$ to the right.

So $\operatorname{im}{f} = \operatorname{im}{k \circ h \circ g} = 1 + \mathbb D$ and the real part is $\operatorname{Re(im}{f)} = [0,2]$ so that the supremum is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$Re(iz^3+1)\le |iz^3+1|\le |iz^3|+|1|=|i|.|z^3|+1=|i|.|z|^3 +1=|z|^3+1\le 1^3+1=2$. Therefore $ 2$ is an upper bound.And we have equality throughout the previous sentence when $z=i$,  so no  value less than $2$ can be an upper bound.