# Compute the least upper bound of the set of all real numbers of the form $Re(iz^3+1)$ such that |z|<2.

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please tell me how to begin? I found another question similar to this but the final result I get is 9. Is this correct?

EDIT: $Re(iz^3+1)≤|iz^3+1|≤|iz^3|+|1|=|i|.|z^3|+1=|i|.|z|^3+1=|z|^3+1<2^3+1=9$

So the supreme is less than 9?

Comment: Naive Approach: Let $z=x+iy$. Expand. Take the Real part. Conclude.

Comment: The supremum is $9$. The [other problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426199/compute-the-least-upper-bound-of-the-set-of-all-real-numbers-of-the-form-reiz) you mention had the condition as $|z| \le 1$ instead of $|z| \lt 2\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to consider here is the fact that is that Re (z) is always less than or equals to modulus of z. Your answer I think can be found here.

[Compute the least upper bound of the set of all real numbers of the form $Re(iz^3 +1)$ such that $|z| \leq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426199/compute-the-least-upper-bound-of-the-set-of-all-real-numbers-of-the-form-reiz)